# How can I write do noting in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

`ESelect` is a `enum` structure. I hope it will do noting when it is `ESelect.NoAction` in the following code.

It will cause compile error if I write `;` after `ESelect.NoAction ->`, how can I fix it?

**Code**

```
aHomeViewModel.selectAction.observe(mLifecycleOwner, {
  when(it) {
    ESelect.SelectAll - > binding.chSelect.isChecked = true
    ESelect.UnselectAll - > binding.chSelect.isChecked = false
    ESelect.NoAction - > ; //It will do nothing
  }
})

enum class ESelect {
  SelectAll,
  UnselectAll,
  NoAction
}
```

Comment: I'm not an specialist, what if you put `{ }`?

Comment: Put `Unit` instead, `{}` is also another option but may seem noisy (intended for multiple statements).

Comment: Perhaps use `ESelect.NoAction -> null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could return Unit (which is like void in Java). The code will look like:

```kotlin
aHomeViewModel.selectAction.observe(mLifecycleOwner, {
    when(it) {
        ESelect.SelectAll    -> binding.chSelect.isChecked = true
        ESelect.UnselectAll  -> binding.chSelect.isChecked = false
        ESelect.NoAction     -> Unit
    }
})
```

See the Docu: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/

Answer (score 1):

You could use `when` as an expression instead of a statement, and for the `NoAction` case assign the existing value:

```
binding.chSelect.isChecked = when (it) {
    ESelect.SelectAll -> true
    ESelect.UnselectAll -> false
    ESelect.NoAction -> binding.chSelect.isChecked
}
```

Or use `if`:

```
if (it == ESelect.SelectAll) {
    binding.chSelect.isChecked = true
} else if (it == ESelect.UnselectAll) {
    binding.chSelect.isChecked = false
}
```